# SQL Query - Return Text based on numeric value

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to work out a query where the query will perform a count (total) on a specific column. If the count is greater than 0, I want to display YES and display NO if the returned count is zero.

So, if I a query as this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ProblemID)
FROM dbo.ProblemInfo
WHERE (ProblemID IN (100,101,309,305,205,600,500)) AND (DEPID = '10866')
```

that will actually be a subquery, how do I get the subquery to display "YES" when the returned count is greater than 0 and NO if the count is 0?

I appreciate any insight and help.

Comment: which DB are you using (Oracle / SQL Server / Postgresql...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate way of querying that.

```
IF EXISTS(
            SELECT *
            FROM dbo.ProblemInfo
            WHERE (ProblemID IN (100,101,309,305,205,600,500))
            AND (DEPID = '10866')
        )
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Yes'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'No'
    END
```

What I like about this method is that, for enormous data-sets, it should be noticeably faster.

Comment: THis is especially interesting. While speed is always not a huge factor but it is important to be aware of. I will have to try this out this query. I appreciate the help very much.

Answer (score 3):

```
select isnull(
    SELECT MAX('YES')
    FROM dbo.ProblemInfo
    WHERE ProblemID IN (100,101,309,305,205,600,500)
    AND DEPID = '10866'),
'NO')
```

This is a trick to return either `YES` if there's at least one matching row, or `null` if not.

The wrapping `isnull` call then turns a `null` into a `NO`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(ProblemID) FROM dbo.ProblemInfo WHERE (ProblemID IN (100,101,309,305,205,600,500)) AND (DEPID = '10866')) > 0 
THEN 'YES' 
ELSE 'NO' END 
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: This is about where I was starting to head with my query. I do not use SQL regularly so I forget the finer points. THis is good.

Answer (score 0):

you can use case when.

```
SELECT 
case 
when COUNT(ProblemID) = 0 then 'NO'
else 'YES'
end
FROM dbo.ProblemInfo WHERE (ProblemID IN (100,101,309,305,205,600,500)) AND (DEPID = '10866')
```

Comment: Interesting. I forgot to mention that I am using MS SQL however this is a good query to keep handy. Thanks